# How to show date x-axis labels every 3 or 6 months in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I generate a plot with code below:

```
ggplot(reshaped_median, aes(x= Month_Yr, y = value))+ 
  geom_line(aes(color = Sentiments)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Sentiments)) + 
  labs(title = 'Change in Sentiments (in median)', x = 'Month_Yr', y = 'Proportion of Sentiments %') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

But as you can notice the dates labels in x-axis are too dense, so if I want to it displays date quarterly or on the half year (every 3 or 6 months).

The values from `Month_Yr` are with format `%Y-%m`.

How could I do that? Thanks.

Comment: you may want to use `scale_x_date` for it.

Comment: Yes, I find this function, but I dont know how set `scale_x_date(...)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First convert date by: `df$Month_Yr <- as.Date(as.yearmon(df$Month_Yr))`

Then use this can solve the issue:

```
ggplot(reshaped_median, aes(x= Month_Yr, y = value))+ 
  geom_line(aes(color = Sentiments)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Sentiments)) + 
  #Here you set date_breaks  ="6 month" or what you wish
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b-%d",date_breaks  ="3 month")+
  labs(title = 'Change in Sentiments (in median)', x = 'Month_Yr', y = 'Proportion of Sentiments %') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: It raises an error `Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Comment: `Month_Yr` is created with `df$Month_Yr <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%Y-%m")`

Comment: I try with `scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y-%m", date_breaks  ="3 month")` also gives same error

Comment: I add this: `df$Month_Yr <- as.Date(as.yearmon(df$Month_Yr))`, it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Suggest noting that as.yearmon comes from the zoo package.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way. With `scale_x_date` you can manipulate the breaks on your x-axis easily.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

data <- tibble(
  Month_Yr = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010/01/01"), to =  as.Date("2020/01/31"), by = "month"),
  Value = runif(121, min = 0, max = 150)
)


p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Month_Yr, y = Value)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "6 months")
p
```